# Can I place a picture in the email signature on an iPad Air?

Tags: ios, mail.app, ipad

I am new to apple, so please forgive the simplicity, but I cannot figure out how to paste my logo pic in my mail signature.  I just  bought the IPAD Air last week, and I want to set up my company signature in the mail app.  I tried to copy and paste the signature from my GoDaddy workspace email, but the picture would not paste.  I couldn't figure out how to save and upload it either like you could on a PC.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put an image in your signature on iOS. If you use Macmaniman's strategy of pasting in an image, the image will show up in settings, but not in an email. (tested on iOS 7)

A workaround is to insert the company logo into each email as you are writing it. However, I don't see why you would want to do this. It's a lot of work and your recipients will probably be annoyed because your images are wasting space in their mail account.

Answer (score 0):

settings - mail, contacts, calendar- signatures

also just **tap and hold** to save an image from anywhere... basically your *"control + c/v/x"* are all done from **tap and hold**

Comment: Ok, but how do I insert the photo into my mail signature? When I tap the space I want to put it, the only options are paste and select all

Comment: what happens if you first copy your image in the photo app then paste the image in the signature?